# Validations and Relations responsabilities for models features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

```
 class Project < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :description
 end

 class Description < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :project
 end
```

- References are on description migration/model.

At this point, I can't save a Description in DB if there's no Project attached to it.
But I can create a Project without description.

In my case I would like to forbid the creation of a Project if it doesn't have a description.

I think at two ways of doing it:

The first is to add a "has_one :project" in Description class, and a "belongs_to :description" in Project
The second would be to put a validation in Project like "validates :description, presence: true"

I'm not sure of what I should prefer. First option seems messy to me, I already put relations between models, so if I add one more for the same two models I feel like it's too much.

And I'm not sure if it's a validation responsability (to forbid project creation if there's no description), or if it's a database/relations responsability. Because as I said, just with ActiveRecord I can't create a Description without a Project, isn't it a bit like a validation ?

And in anycase I guess my "validates" for second choice is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Rails docs, this should require a `Description` to be present to create a `Project`:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :description, required: true
 end
```

It can be found about 2/3 the way down the page. Search for `required`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html